# Anyone know any DB2 experts?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We seem pretty well covered for Oracle, SQL-Server and MySQL - but looking at [the questions tagged db2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2) it's obvious that we are lacking anyone regular on the site.

Is there any way we can contact [Andrew](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/620/andrew) or [Fred](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/615/fred) and encourage them to visit more often (see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/773/how-do-i-join-two-tables-on-two-different-instances-of-db2) for "why them?")

Failing that, perhaps someone else on the site knows a DB2 DBA who they can ask?

Answer (score 3):

So we have a registered user who visited our site four times three months ago.

And an unregistered user (who used a fake email address to come to the site *once*)

What we can do is work on having high quality content that attracts users doing google searches. We can work on promoting the site.

But I'm not sure harping on a couple drive-by users is worth the effort. Sounds harsh, but. >_<

Thanks to @RebeccaChernoff for the nuggets of wisdom inherent in this post ;)

Comment: We seem to be attracting decent questions. I was concerned because my first visit was very nearly my last: It looked to me that the site was mainly for SQL Server and MySQL at the time. Wasn't really expecting there to be a magic bullet - but maybe you do have ideas about "promoting the site" nthat you'd like to share?

Comment: A few of us have been trying to dream up some good solid hooks to get into the communities. I mainly suggest trying to infiltrate existing communities and getting in touch with their leadership and getting them to see the light behind SEI and looking for their evangelistic help. That's about all I got. I've put some feelers out even as recently as this past week, and I evangelize to all the geeks I know, dba's or not, so ...

Comment: let us know if the community team can help with sponsorship of events, swag, conferences, etc to raise awareness. And remember, high quality Q&A is Job #1 -- where there is quality, other quality users *will* follow.

Comment: @JeffAtwood as soon as I get feedback from any of the feelers I've put out, I'm more than happy to touch base with the RCs via the numerous methods at my disposal. :D